# What is the origin of Bhumihars?

Tags: caste-system, ancestry

Bhumihars are one of the abundant tribes of UP and Bihar. They are referred to as descendants of Lord Parshuram. As Lord Parshuram was a sage how can he have descendants? If he was married who was his wife and is it mentioned in any scriptures or religious books about the descendants of Parshuram? [This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhumihar) refers about the bhumihars. What is the exact origin story of Bhumihar who are also termed as Bhumihar Brahmins?

Comment: This does not seem to be rlated to hinduism!

Comment: I think Bhumihar Brahmins belong to Hindu religion and Lord Parshuram also !!

Comment: Yes, but no scriptures were writte after the emergence of the bhumihars

Comment: Related [What is the story of Parashurama's wife Dharani?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3912/3500)