# What were the exact reasons of birth of all the Shivansh?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, shiva-lingam

After going through stories of Shivansh, following patterns happened to be common in all-

- All were against Lord Shiva. Even they wanted to kill Mahadeva!
- All were against Devas despite of the fact they were born out of MahAdeva.(i.e, when actually they were Devas)
- All resulted into the great chaos.
- All had Asuri Pravritti or supported Asuras?
- In short, why they weren't calm or Yogi like Lord Shiva when they were Shivansh?

So, is there any subtle reason of their birth? Can anyone tell the exact reasons of their birth? 
As far as I remember these were the Shivansh.

1. **Jalandhar**
2. **Andhak**
3. **Rohitang**

Comment: One possible explanation is Shiva Purana says "Rudre to Gunadhãmani" Rudra is full of attributes (Satwa, Rajas and Tamas)... these Amshas might be born of his Tamo Gunas... source of that verse is [from here.](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10584/how-does-the-names-and-events-reoccur-in-different-manvantara-or-kalpa-or-differ/15573#15573)

Comment: Yes @tezz but I think there should be a reason. I learnt they born out to balance the Karmas of Lord Shankar when Lord Shankar sided Devas more than Asuras directly or indirectly. But I don't know whether this claim has scriptural basis or not.

Comment: Yes, something like that might be... also the SataRudriya states "Namo Akkhidate cha Prakhhidatte cha". Salutations to him who troubles little and to him who troubles most.... So, these Amshas might be to punish (trouble) Devas as per their Karmas...

Comment: Yes, but would be better if some scriptural basis is found.