# Why there are the vedic ritual in Mīmāṃsā school of thought?

Tags: purva-mimamsa

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44487/22556

According to this answer mimamsa preform vedic ritual to attain Moksha but according to both schools God do not play any role unlike dvaita Vedanta there God is karma enforcer.

**So why do they preform vedic ritual and to whom they are dedicated ; if they do not believe that God plays any role then why do they preform vedic rituals**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If the Purva Mimamsa school doesn't accept the corporeality of the Devas, then how does it explain their actions?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21105/if-the-purva-mimamsa-school-doesnt-accept-the-corporeality-of-the-devas-then-h)

Comment: There are lots of questions like this about the purva mimamsa school on this site. There are also good answers to those questions.