# After lives of Lord Narasimha and Lord Varaha

Tags: vishnu, narasimha, varaha

Lord Narasimha and Lord Varaha are incarnations of Lord Vishnu but unlike other incarnations eg, Lord Rama, Lord Krishna, Nara-Narayana, Lord Vamana, etc, I do not see them to be having a full life span. They seem to be incarnations for fulfilling a purpose and as soon as that purpose is fulfilled we donot find what more happened in their life. Ofcourse there is a story of Lord Narasimha fighting Lord Shiva who was in Sharabha form but not more than that. Do we have any account of lives of Lord Narasimha and Lord Varaha apart from their main incidents of killing of Hiranyakashyapa and Hiranyaksh and the one I briefed above. Also, is their any mention of whether they are still alive or about their death or submerging into Lord Vishnu.

Comment: The Narasimha avatara was only for Prahalada. Once, the mission was completed, Lord disappeared. Regarding Lord Varaha also Lord resided on Venkatachala hills, till the arrival of Lord Srinivas. People say that he eternally resides on Venkatachala, Tirumala. Death is only for demi gods, but not for the supreme Lord's avataras.

Comment: Varaha is still alive on the Earth to this day In Tirupati, on the Western bank of the Swami Pushkarini lake, as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2086/36  Regarding Narasimha, there is a folk tale that after defeating Hiranyakashipu he married an incarnation of Lakshmi called Chenchu Lakshmi, who was a local tribal woman who lived in the area.  But I'm not sure if that has a basis in Hindu scripture.  In any case, I don't think Narasimha is still there on the Earth.

Comment: But yeah, you're right that Vamana has been living a full life; he even has grandchildren, as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/559/36

Comment: @Krishna This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27226/discussion-on-question-by-aby-after-lives-of-lord-narasimha-and-lord-varaha).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Believe it or not, but narasiṁha's soul is very well present on [at least] Earth [i.e., Bhū loka]. I've had the fortune to meet him. He's exactly as is described in the scriptures, his krodha, his gesture, his big eyes  (I was shocked how accurate our scriptures are after realising that!) etc.

Comment: @VinayaŚiṣya Hmm, that's interesting, what were the circumstances of your encounter?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I cannot reveal to you much details like under what circumstances it was, how etc., but I DID met him in person and it'd seem though his body has perished over with time but he's still on Earth helping people and is omnipresent on Earth. Some people meet divinities mostly in dreams...and I did too including one of my deceased grandfather who came to help me and revealed that my stolen-laptop was going to be retrieved and under what circumstances..  but as far as narasiṁha's concerned, I met him in person. BTW, I'm looking for Bhaviṣya Purāṇa...grateful if you can help me out.

Comment: @VinayaŚiṣya Well then, it may not be Narasimha, because his body is made of Shuddha Sattva and thus not subject to decay; see this chapter of Vedanta Desikan's Rahasyatraya Sara: http://gdurl.com/Kq6J

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Maybe the import of « Śuddha Sattva » is misunderstood and rather it means that Śrī Narasiṁha has more paramātmā-aṁśa than any other avatāra of Viṣṇu. By this it is very evident because when I met him, although he could understand what we say to him but he couldn't fully descend to the human-like state like anyone else (for e.g., like Kālī - by this I would like to reveal that I have also met Kālī). His consciousness was vastly different and believe me or not he is exactly as is depicted in the purāṇādi texts. He is ever angry, so angry as if he can gulp someone within secs.

Comment: @VinayaŚiṣya No, it has nothing to do with more Paramatma Amsa.  I suggest you read the chapter I linked to, it's talking about the bodies of avataras of Vishnu in general.  The bodies of incarnations are not subject to decay. Narasimha's body today would look exactly like it looked on the day he killed Hiranyakashipu.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan either way, the answer to this question is Yes i.e., he's present. Though I am not any authority and would like to stay humble, yet what I have seen and lived in real life cannot be ignored. Such matters are usually kept secret from the mainstream public and if I wished I'd have remained silent on this too.  But I chose to come forward only to quench the jijñāsā of those looking for ans. Like me many exist who have met him and most of them, being sādhus-like and what not, are living in a world which is unknown ordinary people where they share connection to several divinities.